# read_json function in pandas - python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a JSON file with 194 elements, but when using the function read_json('input.json') I only get 100 elements. I tried pd.options.display.max_rows = 999, but sill have the same problem.

Here is my code :

```
import pandas as pd 
data=pd.read_json('input.json')
pd.options.display.max_rows=200
print(data)
```

Comment: What is the value of `len(data)`?

Comment: read_jason is not a function, do you mean read_json?

Comment: Don't try to print the whole dataset. Using `data.head()` is enough for initial exploratory analysis. And use `len(data)` es suggested by trivvz.

Comment: len(data) gives 100

Comment: @Amen0 so if it gives 100 that means this is not a display problem but a problem with reading data - modifying `pd.options.display.max_rows` won't help you here. You have to look for an issue in your `input.json`. You can try to modify it and check how it impacts the `len(data)`

Answer (score 0):

I had solved the issue, and as @trivvz said this was a problem with the data. The API  that I was using had only 100 elements per page.